# Ajax: bulk url list in textarea sending requests one after another and display answers repetitive

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to input a bulk list of urls in a textarea (each line contains 1 url). After submitting the form, the ajax should get one url, doing php stuff with this url, sending the result back, take another url, do the same and repeat. While the hole thing is working there should be displayed a loading circle ("ajax-loader.gif") and the results should be displayed one after another, like:

[Submit] -> loading -> result 1st-url -> loading -> add result 2nd-url one line under result 1st-url -> loading -> add result 3rd-url one line under result 2nd-url -> ...

I'm doing this whole ajax/js stuff since yesterday - so i'm not very experienced in that way - the php is working with no errors. my main problem is the js/ajax request; how to recieve the result, doing stuff with it,.. This is what i've written so far:

**js/ajax (w.o. jquery cause i dont like the notation):**

```
function send (){
  var url = document.getElementById('comment').value.split('\n'); //split input from textarea in array
  document.getElementById("load").innerHTML='<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />';

for(var i=0;i<url.length;i++) {
  http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open("POST", "check.php", true);
  http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
  http.send("name=" + url[i]);

  http.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=http.responseText;
    }
  }
}   
}
```

**html:**

```
<form method="post" action="" name="Formular">
<textarea cols="100" rows="10" id="comment"></textarea><br/>
<input type="button" value="Absenden" onClick="send()">
</form>
<div id="load"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**php:**

```
<?php
$url = $_POST['name']; //get url
..do funky stuff..
echo $result; //result is a simple string if an element on that url exists
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is make your ajax function recursive,  eg on completion, it calls its self, rather than using a loop.

Here is a full example, contained in a single php file, called ajax-example.php:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    sleep(1);
    echo $_POST['name'];
    die();
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="load">doin nothin</div>

<textarea name="n" id="comment" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<br/>
<button onclick="send()">send</button>
<div id="result"></div>



<script type="application/javascript">
    function send (){
        var url = document.getElementById('comment').value.split('\n'); //split input from textarea in array
        var current = 0;
        var total = url.length;
        document.getElementById("load").innerHTML='loading';//'<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />';
        //call ajax for 1st time
        ajax();

        function ajax(){
            //if there are urls left to process
            if(current < total){
                var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                http.open("POST", "/ajax-example.php", true);
                http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
                http.send("name=" + url[current]);
                //increment current marker
                current++;
                http.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if (http.readyState == 4) {
                        var res = document.getElementById("result");
                        res.innerHTML=res.innerHTML + http.responseText +"</br>";
                        //recursive call
                        ajax();
                    }
                }
            }else{
                //we are done, remove the loading img
                document.getElementById("load").innerHTML='finished';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just to add, dont discount jQuery just because you dont like the syntax, it can make your life a lot easier for non trivial dom manipulation

Comment: Thx alot! Worked like a charm after hijacking my php into it - never thought about recursion.